# lua:bad argument #2 to '?'(start index out of bound)

Tags: linux, lua, ubuntu-16.04, torch

[image]

Recently I use torch7 to run a model, but this mistake occurs frequently, which drives me crazy.
Who can help me?

Comment: [with no code, and no other info; no one!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IiqUn.jpg)

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/saakuraa/cvpr16_stereo_public  well  infact,i was running the model of the paper,so the mistake ouucred at the  training script running step2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with torch7 but I'll refer you to this thread, seems to be the same or similar issue, caused by too small of a dataset.

https://github.com/jcjohnson/torch-rnn/issues/201

Comment: alright itried,but failed at last,maybe my method is not right,thanks all the time

Answer (score 0):

When this line is failing in your run:

```
self.val_left[i] = self.ldata[img_id][{{}, {center_y-self.psz, center_y+self.psz}, {center_x-self.psz, center_x+self.psz}}]
```

the stack trace tells us that a function in [Tensor.c](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/generic/Tensor.c#L984) has a failing argument check:

```
static int torch_Tensor_(__index__)(lua_State *L)
{
  ...
  for(dim = 0; dim < ndims; dim++)
  {
    ...
    else if(lua_istable(L, 2))
    {
      ...
      THArgCheck((start >= 0) && (start < tensor->size[cdim]), 2, "start index out of bound");
      ...
    }
  ...
  }
}
```

It is the implementation of the [indexing operator with a table argument to narrow and select](https://torch7.readthedocs.io/en/rtd/tensor/index.html#torch.Tensor.indexing). It seems, the computed first indices in either one dimension is too big/too small.

Try to print the values of `center_y-self.psz` and `center_x-self.psz` to see which one is the culprit and on what end of the interval you exceed the bounds. I cannot give further advice, because I am not familiar with the rest of the code or the data.

Comment: https://bitbucket.org/saakuraa/cvpr16_stereo_public infact it is a code of a paper in 2016 CVPR，thank you all the time

Comment: Where you able to fix the problem, @medori?

Comment: i ran the csript on ubuntu 16.04 LTS(GNU/Linux 4.0.0-21-generic x86_64),a server in my school

Comment: And what were the results? Could you find the problem?

Comment: sry ,i really cant,cuz i'm totally new to this